# Changing the certificate fingerprint for an existing application

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, sha1, google-play-games

I have an existing application that i published in to google play.

All was fine, until I have changed a computer and my sha1 fingerprint changed. Is there a possible way to change the sha1 for an existing application in google play developer console? if not, how can I deal with it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remember, when you publish the app first time on your older computer, you generate a key.keystore in order to [sign the apk file](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) and publish to google play.

You need to have the same file. When you want to sign the apk, it asks if you want to generate a new key or use an existing key. Since you have already generated the key, you should choose existing key.

Comment: Thank you for replaying, So I just did what u said and when I am trying to run my application on my device and to connect to google play services it says "Unknown problem google servers play". the sha1 is the same, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you successfully export your singed .apk file? and then successfully upload in Google play? Did Google play showed: "it takes several hours that your request completed"?

Comment: I just followed your instructions again and now it works! Thank you very much, I just I just use my existing key as you say. and the google play services problem was that I ddnt turn on the drive sdk and the drive api in console.developers.google.com.

Comment: can't find the file. Any other way?

Comment: does SHA1 fingerprint is permanent for a  specific computer and can't change?