# How to change SHA1 in Android application

Tags: android, gradle, keystore, sha1

I change my PC and I'm trying to update my app. I download a hole code from GIT but aplications now have different SHA1. How to change it ? There is an easy way ?

Comment: where you want to change SHA1

Comment: I have all my certificates on google play (apk is already on store) but keys change inside my project in android studio

Comment: I should be same like in google play but I download code from git now I want to made update and keys are different

Comment: You probably need to authorise your new PC to every Google service your apps are using. No need to change something in your app. Just go to your Google Dev account and add the new SHA1

Comment: I can't change SHA1 for app.

Comment: you can't change SHA1 for app which is already uploaded on play store

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979330/changing-the-certificate-fingerprint-for-an-existing-application)

This is for the app that you have updated it in play store initially and now you are going to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe You are talking about app signing with Your developer key in debug mode.
When its built on different PC it is signed with different key.

To avoid this You should be using key generate for project.
You can generate this using keytool:

```
keytool - genkey -v -keystore <filename> -alias <alias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity <validity in days, more than 25 years>
```

Then use signConfig in Your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
                   debug {
                        storeFile file("location of your .keystore file")
                        storePassword "password for keystore"
                        keyAlias "alias of the key"
                        keyPassword "password for the key"
                  }
 }
```

Comment: Not exactly, maybe this way. What if I delete my keystore from my PC, but no google play I have all certificates. Can I create new key using this existing SHA1 etc ?

Comment: I believe You can use existing SHA1 to create new certificate but this would not be the same cert and I'm afraid You won't be able to publish update with apk signed like that.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

So simply use earlier certificate to build the new project.

Steps:
1. Open Project Structure.
2. Add Signing
3. Provide the path of earlier keystore.

Answer (score 0):

android_id = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID).toString();

```
    didsha1 = HashingFunctions.sha1(android_id);
```

you can change sha1 here by assigning some text

Answer (score 0):

First Step 
Go your C drive open Program File ->Open JAVA Folder ->Open Bin and DoubleClick on jarsigner.exe

Then Open Cmd

Go to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin Then Enter
Then Go
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin>keytool -list -keystore "F:\BTG UPDATE BUILD\Beyond_The_Game.jks"

Enter 
JUST Show Enter Kaystoer Password ***** enter your PAssword enter finally Your Release SHA key Getting you 
Thank YOU [image]